# how to interpret the behavior of a ROC curve very close to one

Tags: r, auc

annex the ROC curve of a logit model, which has a very high AUC, how can I interpret the behavior of this curve, I doubt the logit model?

[image: ROC Curve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ROC curve looks like a stair case, it means you do not have too many samples. If there are large number of samples, the ROC curve will look smooth.

In your case, it seems you have very limited sample, and once threshold pass 0.25, the model can do a perfect job.

Conclusion from the figure provided

- The model can do a perfect job for threshold pass 0.25
- There are not too many samples, so the model may not be representative to large data, but overfitting a small set.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. the sample that I have is more than a million observations, it will be that the atypical observations generate this problem or a variable of the logit model. what do you think?

Comment: @Jonas I do not think I understand your comment, but if you have more than 1 million samples, it is very likely most of are the same / have same feature and label.